# Uitableview cell dynamic height

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I am using two custom cells in a tableview. The first cell contains two labels. The second cell contains a label and a view(sub class of GMSMAPVIEW). I have used the following code for dynamic cell height.

```
TableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
TableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0
```

I have set proper contraints for all the cell elements. The problem I am facing is: The first cell is perfect. But the second cell doesnot show me the mapView.(Means the second cell's height is reduced to just 44). Which hides my mapview in that cell. Am I missing anything?

This is the screen shot of my tableview:
[image]

The Essential Information cell is the one with the issue. Constraints for Essential information label are:[image]

Constraints for the mapView are:[image]

Comment: you are using auto layout? autolayout is must for `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: yes I am using autolayout. I think I mentioned about constraints! :)

Comment: ohh, yes, my mistake, did your first cell get's proper height or it's also of 44 ?

Comment: the first cell gets the proper height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must write this code in viewDidLoad

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Next, check your constraints in your xib. Make sure there are no errors.

Then, if you cannot see the map, check if you have a valid API key from Google Dev Console and put it in the appDelegate like this example:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MYAp1KEy-348234239423949294239");
    return true
}
```

You can find more information in the [official documents](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_4_get_an_api_key)

If you have problems to update your mapviews after placing a marker you can follow the official guide [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker)

PS: You can check if you make all steps correctly about your swift google map project follow this step-by-step guide:
[Google Maps iOS SDK Tutorial: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/109888/google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial)

Comment: My maps are working in another view controller. SO it means there is no issue with the key.

Comment: Can you show how do you set mapView cell constraints? Can you see the Google logo or nothing ?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question. Please have a look at my constraints.

Comment: I have set the height inplace of it

Comment: Thank you so much brother!! I added both height and bottom constraints. And it did work!! Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the sequence like below. call estimatedRowHeight first.

```
TableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0
TableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

From viewDidAppear reload the table data like,

```
[TableView reloadData];
TableView.reloadData() //for swift
```

Comment: No hope! Didn't help :(

Comment: have you tried to reload table data from viewdidload? if yes then there should be problem of your constraints. ckeck your mapview's size and constrains.

Comment: I have added the constraints to my question. I don't feel if any thing is missing.

Comment: According to your question update you have missed constraint bottom space to superview.

Answer (score 0):

can you once try changing the sequence of lines in your code in **viewDidLoad()**

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```